# Can't download "Basic typing" pack in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

To search emojis, I need the basic typing pack installed:

[image]

But this button doesn't work at all—nothing happens when I press it:

[image]

I have Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809 10.0.17763.914.

Comment: LTSC does not support many functions end users expect. Microsoft intends this product for special use systems such as kiosks. If you are trying to use this on a normal use computer you should expect things to not work as you may expect: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/ltsc/

Comment: Only things that depend on the Store do not work on LTSC. I didn't know you needed the Store for those language packs, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed the [English (United Kingdom) Local Experience Pack in the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/english-united-kingdom-local-experience-pack/9nt52vq39bvn?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

There is an [article on windowspro.de](https://www.windowspro.de/wolfgang-sommergut/local-experience-packs-sprachen-fuer-windows-10-ab-1809-server-2019-installieren) (in German) talking about changes to how Microsoft distributes language packs since Windows 10 1803/1809.
[edit] The article mentions that the buttons in the options are non-functional.

[edit] Here is basically the same [article in English on 4sysops.com](https://4sysops.com/archives/local-experience-packs-add-languages-to-windows-10-and-server-2019/).